# Get Date Taken of an image

Tags: java, image

I want to find the "Date Taken" of an image and not "date modified" or "date created". Though I have found some links on stackoverflow, but none could retrieve it. The image format is: tiff and RAW.

Using `javax.imageio`, I wrote the below program, but it prints nothing. Which means there is no `reader` available

```
        File file = new File( fileName );
        ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);
        Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);            
        if (readers.hasNext()) {
            // pick the first available ImageReader
            ImageReader reader = readers.next();
            // attach source to the reader
            reader.setInput(iis, true);
            // read metadata of first image
            IIOMetadata metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0);
            String[] names = metadata.getMetadataFormatNames();
            int length = names.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                System.out.println( "Format name: " + names[ i ] );
                displayMetadata(metadata.getAsTree(names[i]));
            }
        }
```

Using the core java libraries, is there a method to access "date taken" and not "date created" or "date modified".
Further the `data taken` info is available as I can see that from image properties in OS

EDIT: It turns out that `readers` iterator has nothing with it. i.e.e size 0. It is only happening for tiff and raw images. Works well with jpeg

Comment: Have you examined the metadata trees to see if you can find the date? Post what you have found so far.

Comment: Yes. It prints nothing. If the image was jpeg, it did print information like compression etc but not date taken

Comment: Maybe the reader is set to ignore meta data: `System.out.println(reader.isIgnoringMetadata());`

Comment: The thing is, it is not entering the if clause only. i.e. only if the readers.hasNext() is true then I can have your print statement. For some reasons, there are no readers available

Comment: Nothing requires that metadata be present in an image.  You cannot depend on it being there.

Comment: Meta data is indeed present as I can see from OS by checking properties

Comment: Last I checked, the Java core API only supports JPEG and PNG in most aspects of image interaction.  This could be why you're encountering success with jpeg images, but failure for tiff and raw files.

Comment: @Vulcan Thanks a lot. Are you aware of any link that can confirm that

Comment: @Jatin I believe I saw that in some third-party image API's "About" section, which praised itself for supporting formats which Java's core API did not. I may have read it in the core API documentation itself, but I can't recall for sure.

Comment: @Vulcan ok. Thanks anyways. I have found this http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/exif/ and it is doing the job. Just that I wanted to avoid it and use native libraries itself

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I could not find any solution using java core libraries. Found a library called [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) which does the job.

More info can be found [here.](http://www.geekcap.com/campus/Java/article/56)